# What does it mean for "Bootstrap" to be precompiled?

Tags: web-development, web-applications

I was reading the Bootstrap Getting Started docs, and I came across "Pre-Compiled Source" as a feature. Upon downloading the package, I just found `.js`, `.css`, and some image files. What is there to be "pre-compiled"? Doesn't it all compile in the browser upon page load? I'm guessing this means that it was compiled and tested before shipping, but I don't understand why this would need to be advertised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) uses [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) files to generate CSS files. The pre-compiled version contains the output from LESS. If you want to modify Bootstrap you'll need the source and then compile the LESS files into CSS.

The term *compile* is the word LESS uses on their website.

http://lesscss.org/

> Doesn't it all compile in the browser upon page load? I'm guessing this means that it was compiled and tested before shipping, but I don't understand why this would need to be advertised.

No, Bootstrap can not run in the browser without the CSS being compiled using LESS.

Answer (score 8):

Precompiled, as it relates to Javascript and CSS, is a misnomer.  When some Javascript or CSS library or framework says it is precompiled, what they usually mean is that it is minified or obfuscated.

I think the term has been popularized for use with these frameworks to give the impression that being "compiled" somehow makes them more efficient or "performant" (another made-up term), but it is a misuse of the word all the same.

What they *may* be referring to is the use of the LESS *preprocessor* to produce CSS that is compatible with the browser.

Comment: feel better now? :)

Comment: I added a clarification, and upvoted your answer.

Comment: You and I need to find more fun things to do on a Friday night ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes a lot of sense. I marked @MathewFoscarini, because it answers the question specifically for future readers.